# I have a .php file and none of my external css or javascript is working

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I am quite new to PHP.

I built a .php website which I've hooked up to a local test server using MAMP. For some reason, although I can view the site in my browser (Chrome), and the PHP works (I built a form that sends email), none of the CSS from the external style sheet I linked, nor the javascript from the external javascript file I linked is working.

If I type any of the CSS or script inline, everything works fine. I've used external files many times before in .html files and they have all worked just fine. What am I doing wrong here?

my .php file:

```
<?php

$to = 'email@email.com';
$subject = 'subject';
$message = $_POST['message'];

$message = <<<EMAIL

$message

EMAIL;

$header = '$email';

if($_POST){

    mail($to, $subject, $message);

}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Php Test</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PhpTest.css"/>


<body onload="alertFunction()">

<h1 id="header">Text text text.</h1>

<form action="?" method="post">

<ul>
    <li>
<label for="message">Message:</label>
<textarea id="message" name="message" cols="42" rows="9"></textarea>
</li>
<li>
<input type="submit"  value="Submit"</li>
</li>
</ul>

</form>

<footer>
<script type="text/javascript" src="PhpTest.js"></script>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

my css:

```
#header{
    color:#3C9;
}
```

my javascript:

```
function alertFunction()
{
alert("Alert.");
}
```

Update: I started a new .php in Dreamweaver from scratch. I added no actual PHP code; I just placed a header within the body, linked to an external CSS within the head tag (within the CSS I simply designated the header's color as a blue) and tried that. As it turns out, Dreamweaver will recognize the link and apply the CSS it when I view the site using the design/split screen, however when I try to preview it in Chrome, it fails. I have no idea what this means, but if anyone has any theories they would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Would does your folder structure look like?

Comment: the .php, .css, and .js are all within the same folder (which serves as the server folder for my local server and is a subfolder within htdocs, in case you're familiar with MAMP).

Comment: try to put the links to the js and the css in the `<head>` part of the page

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't work. I've also tried putting the script tags just about anywhere I could think would work, but nothing's worked.

Comment: i was having this problem and i just cleared my cache. A silly mistake i know but worth a try?

Answer (score 4):

I think your `<link rel="stylesheet" .../>` tag must be inside `<head>`

> This element defines a link. Unlike A, it may only appear in the HEAD
>   section of a document, although it may appear any number of times.
>   Although LINK has no content, it conveys relationship information that
>   may be rendered by user agents in a variety of ways (e.g., a tool-bar
>   with a drop-down menu of links).

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-LINK

So:

```
<head>
    <!-- Moved <link/> inside <head></head> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PhpTest.css"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Php Test</title>
</head>
```

**Edit**

Well, I've tried your page. Named the stylsheet file `Phptest.css` where it's `PhpTest.css` in the `.php` file. I got `404 file not found` error because of difference cases of `t`. Make sure that you named the file exactly like what you typed in the `<link/>` tag.

Also if you're using Chrome. Press `F12` and check if there were any errors.

Comment: This didn't work. For some reason the location of my link/script tags doesn't seem to be affecting anything.

Comment: still nothing, and I've checked and double-checked. thanks for the help, regardless; I'm going to just make a simple site from scratch and see if anything changes

Comment: I wish i could help. Sorry. Anyways, search for the best practices about writing `html` and including external files to it.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me just fine, however I know that case sensitivity can be an issue when moving pages from server to server... I would try renaming your files (and the links in the html page as well) to implement all lowercase...

Comment: can I ask what kind of server you're using to test this?

Comment: I am on Debian Wheezy with Apache 2.4.6 and PHP 5.5.1

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the full url for the location of css and javascript like:

```
href="http://www.domain.com/css_file.css"
```

Answer (score 0):

it works.

However, please make sure your css and js file is under the same folder.

also make sure the file name is exactly the same.  Since it is case sensitive.  I also made a mistake while mis-typed the first time.   After I match the casing it worked.

Comment: the php, css, and js are all within the same folder. do you suggest I put the css and js within a separate subfolder?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is your file naming. Check if the links and the files have the exact name, with all lower and upper cases.

I for myself name all files with just lowercase letters, to avoid this..